# Can I create an ATA of PDA account?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, pda, associated-token-account

I get this error:

```
 "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Create",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]",
  "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
  "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 173513 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction",
```

This is my struct:

```
 #[account(mut,seeds = [VESTERSEED],bump = vesterbump)]
    pub vester: AccountLoader<'info, Vester>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = owner,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = vester,
    )]
```

Here is `vester`. It is a PDA which is used to store some other data.

I use *exactly* the same method given in one answer, but still I get the same error.

One extra thing is that my `mint`is also a program PDA,

```
#[account(init_if_needed,
          payer = owner,
         seeds = [SEED.as_ref()], bump,
          mint::decimals = 6,
          mint::authority = mint)]
pub mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
```

which works like a normal mint perfectly.

I followed the previous process which was successfully executed when the `senderTokens` was ATA of Payer instead of `PDA`, so according to that my program throws an error, when the `systemProgram` tries to create the actual ATA.

Here are the logs:

```
{
  "info": {
    "lamports": 2039280,
    "newAccount": "DP38DWTnLhi7Hv868nTLS8d7x98B8PvviioTYFXyaMGj",
    "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "source": "GXRZrSoaQopRYouxLWmWxsQyzgF223jnAZDbMrSXfb6P",
    "space": 165
  },
  "type": "createAccount"
}
```

Here the owner is `tokenProgram`, but for a PDA it could be different.

I tried to do the same thing in JavaScript:

```
 const vester_ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, vesterPda, true);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        vester_ata,
        vesterPda,
        mint
      )
    );

    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );
```

But I still get the same error [HERE](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2bxqfzoS4Dz4mTKuVJrXpWQwFMCStLRmAR4SLRuknT4kzMeL9fNb1cXyyqGVpyh86yFF2pC88wvx9E6Vn7fpv6BU?cluster=devnet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a PDA can be the authority of a ATA.

How are you determining your PDA and ATA on the client-side? Are you overriding the default `TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` and `ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID`? Based on the error, I'd start there. Otherwise there's probably an issue in how you're deriving your ATA or PDA

1. ATA: Make sure you are getting an ATA allowing owner off curve (since you are using PDA) by setting the 3rd parameter of `getAssociatedTokenAddress` to `true`:

```
import { getAssociatedTokenAddress } from "@solana/spl-token";
//...
const ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, vesterPda, true)
```

2: Vester PDA

```
  const [vesterPda, _vesterBump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from(VESTER_SEED)// Your vester seeds
    ],
    program.programId // make sure this is the program ID for your program
  );
```

3. Make sure your Account context includes the token and associated token programs:

```
    /// Standard Token Program 
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    /// Standard Associated Token Program (for init new ATA)
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
```

Hopefully one of those helps. If not, please share your full account context and client code.

Comment: I am actually following all these steps.

Comment: could it be `associated_token::authority = vester,`, as authority I need `program` instead of `PDA`?

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

So, It turns out `IncorrectProgramId` was for the mint since it was not initialized , what what I had to was

```
 #[account(init_if_needed, payer = owner, seeds = [OKUSEED.as_ref()], bump, mint::decimals = 6, mint::authority = mint)]
    pub mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = owner,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = vester,
    )]
    pub sender_tokens: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
```

putting mint before `sender_tokens`, so mint gets initialized first then it tries to create ATA